# How to check if cell is TRUE, if so assign value one by one (in order) from column?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have three columns, ABC. In column A I have item numbers that all start with letters except for the rows highlighted in yellow, which begin with numbers. Adjacent to those numbers I have a flag, TRUE or FALSE, to indicate whether it has number or letter prefix.

On third column I have a list of item numbers that must be filled in the fields adjacent to TRUE, in sequential order. So for example, `13256` should be filled with `P0257` and then `13674` should be filled with `FN001` etc. Can anyone help with this? Seems easy I just have hit a brick wall ..

Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

**FYI:** Column A has about 60,000 rows, while C has only about 13,000 if that matters.

Comment: Use `INDEX/MATCH` but for the match use the COUNTIF of TRUEs.

Comment: @BigBen: Can you elaborate on the `MATCH()` part? How to use `COUNTIF` of TRUE with it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, meant just `INDEX`... *instead* of `MATCH`, use `COUNTIF`.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort column a a-z and the paste the values from c over. If maintaining the original order is important, you could just add in a column that has the row numbers as values so you can re-sort to the original order.